# Debug backtrace but only for 1 IP

Tags: magento-enterprise, debugging

I know we can enable logging call stacks for all the users in `Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql` class by setting `_logCallStack` to true (in addition to `$_debug` true of course).

Is there a way we can we enable call stack for only certain IP, may be in `index.php` file?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### How to set logCallStack

If this is only for a temporary debugging, I recommend you copy `lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/MySql.php` to `app/code/local/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php` and adjust the settings for `$_logCallStack` there.

You could then add an additional check before each log-output. Something like:

original:

```
if ($this->_logCallStack) {
    $code .= 'TRACE: ' . Varien_Debug::backtrace(true, false) . $nl;
}
```

adjust to:

```
if ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']=="111.112.113.114") { //your ip here
   $this->_logCallStack = true;
}
if ($this->_logCallStack) {
    $code .= 'TRACE: ' . Varien_Debug::backtrace(true, false) . $nl;
}
```

I would not recommend this way as a permanent way of implementing the debugging though. As it is a code pool override of the `Mysql.php` file you have to make sure updates from future versions or patches will be brought to this file manually.

### How to output a backtrace for a specific IP

You can set the Developer IP in the Magento admin and use Magentos built in developer functions.

**Set the developer IP**

System > Configuration > Developer > Developer Client Restrictions

**Check if the IP is allowed as developer IP**

before logging debug information:

```
if(Mage::helper('core')->isDevAllowed()){
//your backtrace & log functions here
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I can do this by @Anshu's answer too. Actually I am already doing logging for certain IPs so that is not a problem. What I want to know is how can I enable `_logCallStack ` for those IPs so that I get full debug backtrace of their requests?

Comment: `_logCallStack` is a protected variable so I cannot change it in `index.php`

Comment: Hi @Kalpesh, I updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks @Anna. I will use this as a temporary solution, as you have also mentioned, until someone comes up with a solution that does not override core file.

Answer (score 2):

I usually used the below code to enable logs for my IP only in index.php

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$allowed = array('MY_IP_ADDRESS');
if (in_array($ip, $allowed)) {
    Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    // other debugging code
}
```

Try it, may it is helpful for you as well.

Comment: Thanks Anshu. I know this, what I want to know is how to enable `_logCallStack` for those IPs to backtrace their requests only.